# Add new class to designer

Tags: c#, .net

Hi all I'm trying to add ColumnsNames to this Derivable DataGridView

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ElroubyLibrary.DataGridViews
{
[Designer(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner))]
public class DerivableDGV : DataGridView
{
    public DGVColumnDic[] ColumnsDictionary { get; set; }\\this one
    public DerivableDGV() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // DerivableDGV
        // 
        this.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
        this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
        this.GridColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
        this.DataSourceChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.DerivableDGV_DataSourceChanged);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
}
```

}

what I want is for user to be able to add this DGVColumnDic

```
namespace ElroubyLibrary.DataGridViews
{
public class DGVColumnDic
{
    public string Target;
    public string Equal;
    public DGVColumnDic() { }
    public DGVColumnDic(string Target, string Equal)
    {
        this.Target = Target;
        this.Equal = Equal;
    }
}
```

}

With designer like this
[visual designer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynYGZ.png)

but it appears strange like you see, How can I make it appears with its variables like this
[DataGridViewColumns in Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeZu5.png)